# Model with namespace - wrong table name (without namespace)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I found a problem in one of legacy applications (outdated rails-3.0.20).
This application has lots of components and nested models. Problem existed only on one of production servers (same environments like other productions and mine dev).

There was model with name space which looks like

```
module Great
  class Item
  end
end
```

Table name was named `great_items`.

When i debug/open it on server with fault i've found that calculated table name was `items` istead of `great_items`.

```
$ Great::Item.all
#=> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: No attribute named `name` exists for table `items`
```

So i thought mby there is simmilar class with same namespace, I've checked it and it wasn't. My 2nd thought was to set table name explicit i tried

```
self.table_name = 'great_items'
# &
set_table_name 'great_items'
```

After this changes i run `rails c` and table name was setted fine:

```
$ Great::Item.table_name
#=> 'great_items'
```

**But when i tried to obtain some items there was a freak error, which i could not understand till now!**

```
$ Great::Item.all
#=> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table 'db.items' doesn't exist: SELECT `great_items`.* FROM `items` WHERE `great_items`.`some_default_scope` = 0
```

As you can see in above example table has correct name for `select` values and in `where` statement, but in `from` value is incorrect.

I was curious so I've checked `ActiveRecord::Base` mysql adapter and there was some kind of catching table name so i tried to `reset_table_name`. Reset helped to setup expected name('great_items') but above errors didn't missed.

Problem dissapeared when i turn of class catching in production enviroment - but it wasn't solution.

Finally I kinda 'solved' this using `reset_column_information` after `set_table_name`, but i think it isn't good solution either.

My question is do you know what really could cause this issue and how to solve it without reloading class cache?

Comment: No. But I checked it now and result is not satisfying:
    `irb(main):001:0> Great::Item.table_name_prefix
    => "great_"
    irb(main):002:0> Great::Item.table_name
    => "items"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumed table names dont take into account the modules, as you noticed.

But as you already know, you can set it yourself, using:

```
self.table_name = 'great_items'
```

---

According to [this doc](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.0.9/ActiveRecord/Base/set_table_name/class), because you use 3.0.x, you have to use:

```
set_table_name "great_items"
```

This must be put on top of your class definition

Comment: I wrote it didn't work out - same result as `set_table_name` & `reset_table_name`. Table name was setted correct but query was builded with wrong table name.

Comment: you sure you did add the `self` ?

Comment: ok what if you use `set_table_name` on top of your class definition?

Comment: I didn't expected it will change something but it did the trick.

Comment: I tried it earlier but before it i loaded some module and then tried to `set_table_name`. After replacing lines everything started work.

Comment: I understand it could be confusing. ruby code is executed at run time so order of lines matters

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
class RenameOldTableToNewTable< ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    rename_table :old_table_name, :new_table_name
  end 
  def self.down
    rename_table :new_table_name, :old_table_name
  end
end
```

Comment: can't change table names cause it will break backward compatibility with other systems. Moreover on other servers this code works only one of them is exception :)

Comment: Then you should go with set_table_name as suggtesed by @apneadiving